# What is the better and faster approach to test button click in Capybara?

Tags: rspec, capybara

What is faster and more proper approach for testing button click in Capybara? I was looking for it in the docs, but there is nothing about speed and performance for both methods.

`find('button[name="some_button"]').click`

`click_button 'Some button'`

I know that those are using different matchers, but that is not the point of my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`click_button` is implemented as

```
find(:button, locator).click
```

which becomes

```
find(:xpath, <complicated XPath including the locator>).click
```

So technically your first example should be slightly quicker (CSS evaluation is quicker in most browsers than XPath) however the speed difference is going to be negligible compared to the rest of the overhead. That being said the "proper" approach is to keep your tests more readable which would mean generally using `click_button` when possible.